# A box contains 6 green and 11 yellow balls

Tags: probability

A box contains $6$ green and $11$ yellow balls. Three are chosen at random. We want to find the probability of the first and the third balls being yellow. Which method of sampling, with replacement or without replacement, gives the higher probability of this event?

My answer 
$$P(y g y)={55\cdot 6\over680}=.4852$$

But my teacher gave me $4$ out of $6$ since he wanted me to find the probability with replacement and without replacement. I don't know how can I find the probability with replacement? Is there a formula for sampling with replacement?

Comment: If you replace the balls after each draw then the probability that any given draw is yellow is $\frac {11}{17}$ and all such events are independent.

Comment: I don't understand your calculation.  The question did not say that the draws went $YGY$ only that the first and third were yellow.  Hence $YYY$ is a valid sequence too.

Comment: Also $P(YGY)=\frac {11}{17}\times \frac 6{16}\times \frac {10}{15}\sim .16176$.

Comment: The nice thing about this problem is you don't really have to do any math to figure it out.  Since replacement can't effect the probability of your first draw, it comes down to your third (the only other one you know the result of).  Are you more or less likely to draw a yellow ball on draw three if you put back the yellow ball you drew on draw one?

Answer (score 1):

**With replacement:**  There are two possibilities.  Either a green or yellow ball is drawn second.  Hence, the probability that a yellow ball is drawn on both the first and third draws is 
\begin{align*}
P(YGY) + P(YYY) & = \frac{11}{17} \cdot \frac{6}{17} \cdot \frac{11}{17} + \frac{11}{17} \cdot \frac{11}{17} \cdot \frac{11}{17}\\ 
                & = \left(\frac{11}{17}\right)^2\left(\frac{6}{17} + \frac{11}{17}\right)\\ 
                & = \left(\frac{11}{17}\right)^2
\end{align*}
which is equal to the probability of selecting a yellow ball twice in two draws with replacement.

Notice that when we are drawing with replacement that there are always $17$ balls in the box, of which $11$ are yellow and $6$ are green.

**Without replacement:**  As above, there are two possibilities.  Either a green or yellow ball is drawn second.  Hence, the probability that a yellow ball is drawn on both the first and third draws is
\begin{align*}
P(YGY) + P(YYY) & = \frac{11}{17} \cdot \frac{6}{16} \cdot \frac{10}{15} + \frac{11}{17} \cdot \frac{10}{16} \cdot \frac{9}{15}\\
                & = \frac{11 \cdot 10}{17 \cdot 16 \cdot 15}(9 + 6)\\
                & = \frac{11 \cdot 10}{17 \cdot 16}
\end{align*}
which is equal to the probability of drawing a yellow ball twice in two draws without replacement.

Notice that when we are drawing without replacement that the number of balls in the box decreases by one on each selection and that the number of balls of a given color that remain in the box depends on which balls have already been selected.

I will leave it to you to determine whether the probability of selecting a yellow ball on both the first and third draws is higher when the balls are drawn with or without replacement.

Comment: With replacement will be the higher

Comment: @rrvbh  That is correct.